# Download image through AFNetworking & edit it

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage, afnetworking

I'm trying to download some image files from a remote server through the AFNetworking (UIImageView+AFNetworking.h) & retrieve the UIImage from it, edit that image. Editing means add that image(downloaded image) on top of another png file.( background image - UIImage )

I have tried several code blocks finally I'm stuck in here . I'm getting a black box only. Can't see the actual server image .

```
-(UIImage *)downloadImages:(NSString *)url{

     UIImageView *downloadedImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,40,40)];

     [downloadedImageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]
                    placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Loading_image"]];

     UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(downloadedImageView.bounds.size, downloadedImageView.opaque, 0.0);
    [downloadedImageView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

    UIImage * img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return img;
}
```

Then I'm calling through that function in a for loop.

```
for( int i=0;i<[Images count];i++){

  NSString *image_Url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",imageURL, imagename];  
  UIImage *downloadimage =[[UIImage alloc]init];

  downloadimage = [self downloadImages:image_Url];

  UIImage *bottomImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"map_marker_black"];

  CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(60, 60);
  UIGraphicsBeginImageContext( newSize );

  [backgroundImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];

  [downloadimage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height) blendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:0.7];

  UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

  UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

}
```

Where am I doing wrong ?  Your help is highly appreciated.  Thanks a lot

Comment: There's a lot wrong here. Lets start with what you are actually trying to do. You seem to download multiple images plus you have one static image in your bundle. Do you want each downloaded image drawn over the background image resulting in one final image or do you want a new set of images - one for each downloaded image?

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. 
I want to download multiple images from the server .. But all the images will be use the same ( one ) background image & they will be saved or return separately ..

Answer (score 0):

A few issues. Lets start with the download code. There is no reason to deal with an image view and drawing it to create an image. Just use the actual image:

```
- (UIImage *)downloadImage:(NSString *)url{
     NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
     UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

    return image;
}
```

The big issue with your original code is that the AFNetworking method you used runs in the background. So you were always trying to draw the "loading" image.

Now the drawing code:

```
// Only need to load this once
UIImage *backgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"map_marker_black"];

// What is the loop used for?
for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < [Images count]; i++){
    // Where does imageURL and imagename come from?
    NSString *imageURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",imageURL, imagename];
    UIImage *downloadImage = [self downloadImage:imageURL];

    CGRect newRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 60, 60);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newRect.size, NO, 0.0);

    [backgroundImage drawInRect:newRect];

    [downloadimage drawInRect:newRect blendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:0.7];

    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    // Do something here with newImage

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
}
```

Note the comments in the code.

Comment: yes .. the bottom image is needed to be load once .. It's correct .. i have an array of image names , but as those are stored in one location base url or server url will be same .. so I'm loading "imageURL" from my config file & append image name for it .. I'll run this code & check ...

Comment: As written though you will download the same image `[Images count]` times. Shouldn't `imageURL` somehow change for each iteration?

Comment: yes .. imageURL SHOULD Be change in each iteration .. that's why I'm appending the image name to the base url .. I did not understand that is it still downloading one image ??

Comment: That's why I asked where "imagename" comes from. Your posted code makes no attempt to change "imagename" in each iteration of the loop.

Comment: Is my answer helping? Are you still having any issues with this?

Comment: Still no luck . 

Actually What I'm doing is Changing the google map marker icon with a customised image when user change the zoom level . So I need to use some caching option, otherwise map is getting stuck for direct download.  

Still I can not see the downloaded image :(

Comment: Have you verified that the downloaded image isn't nil? Maybe the URL isn't correct.

Comment: But you need to verify the image is downloading properly in your code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89869/discussion-between-udaya-sri-and-rmaddy).